# Laravel - Can't establish a second Database connection

Tags: laravel, docker-compose

I have a `Laravel 8` project. Laravel runs on a `sqlite` and I want to import data from an old `mariaDB` Wordpress database into the sqlite. The old wordpress database is running in a **docker container**. And I can also access the database with MySQL Workbench.

But unfortunately I can't create the connection to the Docker database. I get the following `Illuminate\Database\QueryException`:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from `wp_posts` where `post_type` = news)

**Why and what am I missing here?**

#### Here are my relevant settings:

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
docker-compose.yml
version: "3.7"
services:
# ...
  #Mysl Service
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    container_name: laravel-mysql
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./logs/mysql:/var/log/mysql
      - ./dumps/:/home/dumps
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=laravel
      - MYSQL_USER=laravel
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    networks:
      - mynetwork
# ...
volumes:
  db_data:
```

**.env**

```yaml
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite

DB_CONNECTION_WP=mysql
DB_HOST_WP=mysql
DB_PORT_WP=3306
DB_DATABASE_WP="wordpress"
DB_USERNAME_WP=root
DB_PASSWORD_WP=password
```

**database.php**

```php
'mysql_wp' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL_WP'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST_WP', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT_WP', '3307'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_WP', 'wordpress'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_WP', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_WP', 'password'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET_WP', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
],
```

**service/imports/wpNewsImport.php**

```
$data = DB::connection('mysql_wp')
  ->table('wp_posts')
  ->where("post_type", "news")
  ->get();
```

Thanks in advance and btw. happy new year!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the problem. I am so stupid. You have to be inside the app container for the database interactions. Because the app container is in the same docker network as the database container. and i was outside. i.e. all the settings are correct. i just have to log in to the database container via bash.

`docker exec -it laravel-app bash`

Then it works.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your DB_HOST_WP=mysql settings is wrong. There should be a valid DB host address or ip. If you can access the database with MySQL Workbench, than just copy host settings from it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had already tried it and it didn't work. By the way, in another project I did it exactly the same way that the container_name = the HOST name and it worked.

Comment: I found the problem. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70577816/14807111) .And that means that your answer would be correct if I hadn't forgotten to go into the container. +1 from me